# In what sense does forcing increase the width of a set-theoretic hierarchy?

Tags: set-theory, forcing

I've often read that, whereas top extensions increase the *height* of the cumulative hierarchy, forcing extensions increase its *width* (see, e.g., [the answer to this question where's it's said that forcing extensions builds sideways instead of upwards](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1580661/forcing-names-parameters-in-definitions-and-the-iterative-conception-of-set); or see [the last paragraph of John Burgess's review of a number of articles on the iterative conception](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2274241?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)). It has never been clear to me, though, what exactly is meant by "width" in this context.

Is it "width" in the sense of the cardinality of a maximum antichain (see [this Wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antichain#Height_and_width))? Or some other sense?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Width" here is meant in the informal sense of how big each "level" $V_\alpha$ of the cumulative hierarchy is. The point is that, if $W[G]$ is a forcing extension of $W$, then they have the same number of levels, but each level of the extension is at least as large as each level of the original: $$(V_\alpha)^W\subseteq (V_\alpha)^{W[G]}.$$ Moreover, as soon as $\alpha$ is large enough (so that $G$ is $\mathbb{P}$-generic for some $\mathbb{P}\in (V_\alpha)^W$) then this containment is strict. (Assuming $W[G]\not=W$.)

Note that I'm not talking about the *cardinality* of the levels $(V_\alpha)^W$ vs. $(V_\alpha)^{W[G]}$ (since cardinality can change between $W$ and $W[G]$), I'm just comparing them directly as sets (in $W[G]$). And although frequently we'll have $W[G]\models \vert(V_\alpha)^{W}\vert<\vert (V_\alpha)^{W[G]}\vert$, this isn't always true: for instance, if we take $W[G]$ to be a forcing extension of $W$ by by adding a single Cohen real.

*By the way, there's no sloppiness above: since $(V_\alpha)^W\in W$ we'll have $(V_\alpha)^W\in W[G]$, so the forcing extension can talk about levels of the ground model. Surprisingly, even more is true - $W$ will be definable in $W[G]$, by work of Woodin and Laver - but that's not needed here.*

---

The orthogonal notion is that of a *top extension*: $W_1$ is a top extension of $W_2$ if (1) $W_1$ is an end extension of $W_2$ (that is, $a\in W_2, W_1\models b\in a \implies b\in W_2$) - note that this implies that the ordinals of $W_2$ are ordinals in $W_1$ as well - and (2) for each $\alpha\in ON^{W_2}$ we have $(V_\alpha)^{W_2}=(V_\alpha)^{W_1}$. So a top extension only makes the universe *taller*.

For example, if $W\models \alpha$ is inaccessible, then $W$ is a top extension of $(V_\alpha)^W$.

Comment: Thanks! Could I trouble you to expand on the last sentence of the first section a bit ("...I'm just comparing them directly as sets")? Is it just looking for bijections or injections (in $W[G]$) between the sets (as opposed to associating them with a cardinal number)? Or is something else meant by "comparing them directly as sets"?

Comment: @Dennis Just what I wrote above: that each level of $W$ is a subset of the corresponding level of $W[G]$, and (eventually, assuming the forcing extension is nontrivial) this inclusion is strict.